# Why is 'group' used as plurals?

Tags: singular

If a group consists of 5 members and the group is jumping, why should all of 5 members be jumping to express the group is jumping? I mean 'group' is a singular so can't I say 'a group is jumping' even though only one member of the group is jumping?

For more example, there's group A and A consists of A, B and C. A and B eats bread but C doesn't. Though 'group A eats bread' is grammatical?

Comment: That's not the meaning of "a group is jumping".  Is it so in your language?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by 'that's not the meaning of 'a group is jumping''?

Comment: It doesn't mean there exists an element of the group that is jumping.  I don't know any language that works like that. I'd be interested if your language does.

Comment: Is there an actual example behind this question?  I don't think people often say "The group is jumping".  It is grammatical and meaningful but no very useful.  Perhaps there was an actual example of a sentence that you want to say, but you are asking about something simpler??

Comment: It doesn't, also in Korean. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Why would you think it could mean that?  I have an answer written, but I want to understand the context of the question.  Why do you think that "The group is jumping" could mean "One person in the group is jumping"?

Comment: Because 'my body is sick' can mean 'my heart is sick.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The group is jumping" probably means that the individuals in the group are jumping.  But it doesn't have to mean that.  It could be something that the group is doing as a whole.  For example

> The group is united.

It doesn't make any sense to apply "united" to the individuals.

But what about jumping?  If only one in the group is jumping then that is not "the group". If you say something about the group it either has to apply to the group as a whole, or to the individuals in it.

In this case it must mean the individuals.

Now if four people are jumping and one is not, the leader might say

> Come on, the group is jumping!

By which they imply "If you don't start jumping then you are out of the group" as a way of motivating.

Likewise "The group eats bread" can mean the unity of the group or the individuals within the group.  Context would clarify.

The "body is sick/heart is sick" is slightly different, since a sickness of one part of the body affects the whole.